# Vim Tabular: how to ignore long comments

Tags: python, vim, tabular

I use `Tabular` in Vim to align definitions on a data file in Python with some long comments:

```
# A long comment here with many words
param_1 = 42
parameter_2 = 0.25

# Another long comment
para_3 = 'abc'
parameter_number_4 = some_var
```

If I use `Tabularize /=` on the selection, comments are processed as well and since some are long I get:

```
# A long comment here with many words
param_1                               = 42
parameter_2                           = 0.25

# Another long comment
para_3                                = 'abc'
parameter_number_4                    = some_var
```

Which is not what I want. Is there a way to ignore a line starting with "`#`" in selection? So as to obtain something like this:

```
# A long comment here with many words
param_1            = 42
parameter_2        = 0.25

# Another long comment
para_3             = 'abc'
parameter_number_4 = some_var
```

Comment: Running `:Tabularize/=` without a range as indicated will align the current line and matching nearby lines only. You will not see the behavior you described.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use a `global` command instead of a visual selection to tell tabularize what to align.  In your case, like this:

```
:%g/^\s*[^#]/Tabularize /=
```

This finds every line in a file that is *not* a comment and runs `Tabularize /=` on it.  If you want to target more specific lines, you can replace the `%` with a `cmdline-range`.  You could also just directly pass a `cmdline-range` to tabularize like so:

```
:2,3Tabularize /=
```

Relevant help topics:

```
:help cmdline-ranges
:help :g
```

Comment: What I wanted seems to not be possible. The way you tell aligns each "block" individually. But for me, it's good enough.